# Xcode keep debug area closed

Tags: ios, xcode

Everytime I run my app in a simulator debug area opens with console. I'm not really like it, because its only spam in there. I want to see this only if errors, or if i open it by myself. I checked preferences of Xcode and tried to google it, but I didnt found anything.

Comment: "Its only spam in there". ROFL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xcode prefs --> Behaviors.

Find the checked entries under "Running".

One of the behaviors will read something like "Show debugger with Current Views". Un-check those behaviors, or change "show" to one of the other options.